# How can I combine on() and not()?

Tags: jquery

I've got this, but its getting an error:

```
$('#Photocell').on('click', 'div.group:not('.overrideIcon')', function(){...});
```

should I use double quotes inside the not()?

Comment: yes, use double quotes

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
$('#Photocell').on('click', 'div.group:not(.overrideIcon)', function(){...});
```

No need of single quotes for the `overrideIcon` class inside `:not()`

Answer (score 3):

Since there are no spaces, you can simply omit the quotes:

```
$('#Photocell').on('click', 'div.group:not(.overrideIcon)', function(){...});
```

Safer way is inverting the quotes:

```
$('#Photocell').on("click", "div.group:not('.overrideIcon')", function(){...});
```